# Cannot install PG Partman on MacOS - Make returning error `missing separator`

Tags: gnu-make, pg-partman

I am trying to install [pg_partman](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman/issues/451) on my Mac. I have tried both my M1 mac and Intel mac. Both of them return the following error when I run `make install`: `Makefile:27: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Line 27 contains:

```
sql/$(EXTENSION)--$(EXTVERSION).sql: $(sort $(wildcard sql/types/*.sql)) $(sort $(wildcard sql/tables/*.sql)) $(sort $(wildcard sql/functions/*.sql)) $(sort $(wildcard sql/procedures/*.sql))
```

This error is usually due to spaces instead of tabs. However I get this error when I run `make install` on *any* of the released versions of pg_partman. I opened an [Issue](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman/issues/451) with the pg_partman team and they have no issues running `make install`, but I believe they are running it on a Linux machine.

I thought it might be due to my M1 mac but when I run on my Intel mac I get the same error. I'm at a complete loss. Machine details below

MacOS Monterey: 12.3.1

`which make`: `/usr/bin/make`

`make --version`:

> GNU Make 3.81 Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc. This
> is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
> PURPOSE.
>
> This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Using `sudo` in `sudo make install` fixed my issue.